# Can a GraphQL input type inherit from another type or interface?

Tags: graphql

Is it possible to use inheritance with GraphQL input types?

Something like that (this, of course, doesn't work with input types):

```
interface UserInputInterface {
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}

input UserInput implements UserInputInterface {
  password: String!
}

input UserChangesInput implements UserInputInterface {
  id: ID!
  password: String
}
```

Comment: Have you ever figured out answer to your question?  I'm facing the exact same one!

Comment: @LB2 unfortunately not, I'm keeping 2 separate types at the moment repeating properties.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to represent a boolean expression (much like SQL's WHERE clause), and without inheritance, it seems impossible to express an arbitrary boolean expression without possibility of syntax-matching nonsense.  Bummer that it's not part of the language.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

No, the spec does not allow input types to implement interfaces. And GraphQL type system in general does not define any form of inheritance (the `extends` keyword adds fields to an existing type, and isn't for inheritance). The spec is intentionally constrained to stay simple. This means that you're stuck repeating fields across input types.

That said, depending on the way you construct your schema, you could build some kind of type transformer that appends the common fields programmatically based on some meta-data, e.g. a directive. Here's [one such implementation](https://blog.letterflow.io/inheritance-in-graphql-when-and-how-to-use-it-d4bef4535797).

Better yet, you might be able to solve your problem via composition (always keep [*composition over inheritance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#Benefits) in mind).
E.g.

```
input Name {
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}

input UserInput {
  name: Name
  password: String!
}

input UserChangesInput {
  name: Name
  id: ID!
  password: String
}
```

The client now has to send an object a level deeper, but that doesn't sound like much of a price for avoiding big repeating chunks. It might actually be good for the client as well, as they can now have common logic for building names, regardless of the query/mutation using them.

In this example, where it's only 2 simple fields, this approach is an overkill, but in general - I'd say it's the way to go.

Comment: Could your example be "extended" further by using the second type in the third one?  ```input userChangesInput { userInput: UserInput, id: ID! }``` ?

Comment: @WhatWouldBeCool Of course, you can compose the types freely.

Answer (score 17):

Starting with the [June2018 stable version of the GraphQL spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Input-Object-Extensions), an Input Object type can *extend* another Input Object type:

> Input object type extensions are used to represent an input object type which has been extended from some original input object type.

This isn't inheritance per se; you can only extend the base type, not create new types based on it:

```
extend input MyInput {
  NewField: String
}
```

Note there is no name for the new type; the existing `MyInput` type is extended.

The JavaScript reference implementation has [implemented Input Object extensions](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1095) in [GraphQL.js v14](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1095#issuecomment-395815345) (June 2018), though it's unclear how to actually [pass the extended input fields to a query](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1095#issuecomment-493726255) without getting an error.

For actual type inheritance, see the [graphql-s2s library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-s2s).

Comment: @kaqqao ok, I would now say that both answers are valuable choices, so have upvoted both.  I do like your composition approach, but for cases of adding a few fields, the new extends keyword seems like a simpler approach.

Answer (score 4):

It's doable using a custom directive.

### Code Summary

```js
const typeDefs = gql`
  directive @inherits(type: String!) on OBJECT

  type Car {
    manufacturer: String
    color: String
  }
  
  type Tesla @inherits(type: "Car") {
    manufacturer: String
    papa: String
    model: String
  }
  
  type Query {
    tesla: Tesla
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        tesla: () => ({ model: 'S' }),
    },
    Car: {
        manufacturer: () => 'Ford',
        color: () => 'Orange',
    },
    Tesla: {
        manufacturer: () => 'Tesla, Inc',
        papa: () => 'Elon',
    },
};

class InheritsDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
    visitObject(type) {
        const fields = type.getFields();
        const baseType = this.schema.getTypeMap()[this.args.type];
        Object.entries(baseType.getFields()).forEach(([name, field]) => {
            if (fields[name] === undefined) {
                fields[name] = { ...field };
            }
        });
    }
}

const schemaDirectives = {
    inherits: InheritsDirective,
};
```

### Query:

```
query {
  tesla {
    manufacturer
    papa
    color
    model
  }
}
```

### Output:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "tesla": {
      "manufacturer": "Tesla, Inc",
      "papa": "Elon",
      "color": "Orange",
      "model": "S",
    }
  }
}
```

Working example at https://github.com/jeanbmar/graphql-inherits.

Answer (score 1):

If you came here looking for an explanation for the "implements", keyword, here it is:

> An object type must be a super‐set of all interfaces it implements. The object type must include a field of the same name for every field defined in an interface.

(Excerpt taken from the [June 2018 GraphQL spec](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/).)

Here's an example

```
interface Foo {
  id: ID!
  foo: Int!
}

type Bar implements Foo @entity {
  id: ID!;
  foo: Int!;
  bar: Int!;
}
```

So the `Bar` type doesn't *inherit* from the `Foo` interface, but it *implements* it. The former must include all the fields that are listed in the latter.

I think that this is a nice way to annotate types that should be like other types.

Comment: As stated by the question, the "implements" keyword will only work with `types` and not with `inputs`