# Can you use fragments in graphql server schema file

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

Can you use fragments in graphql server schema file? Could you please point me to an example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Fragments are defined for operations (queries) only. In other words, the client defines them ad-hoc, not the server in its schema.
If what you're looking for is to reuse a bunch of definitions, I'm afraid you're constrained to implementing an interface, or just good ol' [composition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45554361/294657). Most implementations also support [type extensions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html#extend-types), graphql-java certainly does.